# 3 athletes running

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Three athletes $A_1, A_2, A_3$ run a race.

Let $E_{ij}$ denotes the event that athlete $A_i$ arrives before athlete $A_j$, and let $E_{ijk}$ denotes the event that athlete $A_i$ arrives before athlete $A_j$ who arrives before athlete $A_k$.

Given that \begin{gather} P(E_{13})=2/3;\\P(E_{23})=1/2;\\P(E_{123})=P(E_{132})=x;\\P(E_{213})=P(E_{231})=y;\\ P(E_{312})=P(E_{321})=z.\end{gather}

1. Find $x, y,z$.
2. Calculate the probability that athlete A<sub>1</sub> comes first.
3. Are the events $E_{13}$ and $E_{23}$ independent ?

---

Any tips to solve this are greatly appreciated!! 
What I understand : 
3. I could show that $P(E_{13}\cap E_{23})= P(E_{13}) P(E_{23})$

*What I don't understand:*

1. What does $P_{123}$ mean?
2. Is $P(E_1\cap E_3) \neq\varnothing$ ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: $\Pr(E_{123})$ is the probability that athlete $1$ finishes first, athlete $2$ finishes second, and athlete $3$ finishes third.  $\Pr(E_{123}) = \Pr(E_{12} \cap E_{23})$ since athlete $1$ must finish ahead of athlete $2$ and athlete $2$ must finish ahead of athlete $3$.  It is not clear how you are defining $E_1$ and $E_3$.  We are only given probabilities that one athlete will finish before another.

Comment: Thanks!! I was trying to use the multiplication rule for $\Pr(E_{123})$.

Comment: I thought of E<sub>1</sub> as an effort to express the probability for (b), which is probably wrong. Thank you!

Comment: How did you decide on independence without calculating $x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out eventually: 
(a) We know that: E<sub>13</sub> = E<sub>123</sub> $\cup$ E<sub>213</sub> $\cup$ E<sub>132</sub>
Thus: P(E<sub>123</sub>)+ P(E<sub>213</sub>) + P(E<sub>132</sub>) = $2\over3$ $\implies$ 2x + y = $2\over3$ (1) 
also: E<sub>23</sub> = E<sub>123</sub> $\cup$ E<sub>231</sub> $\cup$ E<sub>213</sub> and: 
P(E<sub>123</sub>) + P(E<sub>213</sub>) + P(E<sub>231</sub>) = $1\over2$  $\implies$ 2y + x = $1\over2$ (2). 
Solving them system of (1),(2) we get: 
y = $1\over9$ and x = $5\over18$ . 
However (all the possible outcomes are 3! = 6) :
  P( $\bigcup$ E <sub>ijk</sub>) = 1 $\implies$ x + x + y + y + z + z =1
$\implies$ x + y + z = $1\over2$ (3)
 and by substituting the values of x,y to (3) we get: z = $11\over18$. 
(b) P( E<sub>123</sub> $\cup$ E<sub>132</sub>) = P(E<sub>123</sub>) + P(E<sub>132</sub>) = 2x = $5\over 18$ = $5\over 9$ 
(c) P(E<sub>13</sub>) P(E<sub>23</sub>) = $2\over3$ $1\over2$ = $1\over 3$ (4) and:
E<sub>13</sub> = {E<sub>123</sub> , E<sub>132</sub>, E<sub>213</sub> }
E<sub>23</sub> = {E<sub>123</sub>, E<sub>213</sub>, E<sub>231</sub> }. These sets have in common 2 events so: 
P(E<sub>13</sub> $\cap$ E<sub>23</sub>)= $2\over 6$ = $1\over3$ (5)

(4),(5) $\implies$ P(E<sub>13</sub> $\cap$ E<sub>23</sub>)= P(E<sub>13</sub>) P(E<sub>23</sub>), which means that events E<sub>13</sub> and E<sub>23</sub> are independent.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that the situation is interesting: The first two formulas seem to indicate that A1 is the best runner, while A2 and A3 Are equally good. But the last three say that whoever wins, the other two are equally likely to beat each other. For example, A1 usually beats A3, but not if A2 wins the race.

How can this happen? Say A1 is good in sunshine, A2 is excellent in bad weather, A3 suffers in bad weather, but not as much as A1. So if A2 wins, the weather is likely bad, and A3s chances to beat A1 are better than usual.

Find P(E31) and P(E32), which is very, very easy, set up whatever equations you find for x, y and z, and try to solve them.

Comment: Thank you for your help and your edit! I will try!

Comment: I've found the solution but I don't see how P(E31) and P(E32) are relevant